# angular proxy issues getting index.html or cors error

Tags: spring, angular, proxy, cors

Hey everybody i've some issues with my angular client.
whenever i do a post request to my spring backend using a Proxy like this...

```
{
   "/api": { 
      "target": "http://localhost:3000", 
      "secure": false, 
      "changeOrigin": true,
      "pathRewrite": {
          "^/api": "" 
       }
   }
}
```

If I set changeOrigin to False then it works on backend as expected. The login works well. The only thing that's weird is the response in the angular client. Instead of getting the original response from the backend Server I am getting the content of my index.html file of my angular App. The response in httpClient.post.subscribe(...) is just the content of the Index.html File.

Then I tried to set changeOrigin to true. But then nothing works anymore.
I get a cors error and my Spring Backend denies the request. Why that? 
I thought when I wanted cors being disabled on backend then using a proxy is the way to go. At least when it comes to setting up the dev environment.

On backend side my spring security looks like this:

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(
                    (request, response, authException) -> response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED)
            )
            .and().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login", "/authorize").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().formLogin().permitAll();//.and().httpBasic();

}
```

In my browser the client shows me the following errormessage:

[image: errormessage]

Comment: Try `"logLevel": "debug"` and see if it helps figure out what happens

Comment: Also when you make requests to your backend the URLs are `http://localhost:4200/api/...` right?

Comment: yes requests are going to http://localhost:4200/api/login a post requests for example

Comment: I ve turned on debugmode.. it says the request has properly been forwarded to the backend. And even the backend showing it. The only errormessage is within my browser that an access control origin header is missing.

Comment: So you are having an error message concerning the access control origin when your frontend is served on `localhost:4200` and your backend too?

Comment: No Backend runs on 3000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to solve my problem I activated cross origin tokens on backend side.

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
}
```

I thought that wouldn't be necessary if I used a proxy.